# Why does my paper, rock, scissor program not work?

Tags: javascript

Do I need to use a Capital letter?

```
var userChoice=prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice=Math.random();
if (computerChoice>0 && computerChoice<0.33)
   {
     computrChoice=("rock");
   }
else if (computerChoice>0.34 && computerChoice<0.66)
    {
      computerChoice=("paper");
    }
else{computerChoice=("scissors");}
    console.log(computerChoice);
```

Comment: There's no way that this is Java.  `var` isn't a keyword, nor does it have any meaning in that context.

Comment: Looks like Java script.

Comment: you spelled `computrChoice=("rock");` computer wrong.

Comment: This question appears to be off topic because the problem is a typo and the question is therefore not useful for anyone else.

Comment: Also I have no idea what you want to know with "is there needs a Capital letter ?".

Comment: Java(script) is case sensitive. I don't see typos of that nature in your sample though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var userChoice=prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice=Math.random();
if (computerChoice>0 && computerChoice<0.33)
   {
     computrChoice=("rock");        <<---- you have spell error here
   }
else if (computerChoice>0.34 && computerChoice<0.66)
    {
      computerChoice=("paper");
    }
else{computerChoice=("scissors");}
    console.log(computerChoice);
```